# Enum from string, int, etc

Tags: c#, .net, enums, extension-methods, type-conversion

Using extension method we can create methods to convert an enum to other datatype like string, int by creating extension methods `ToInt()`, `ToString()`, etc for the enum.

I wonder how to implement the other way around, e.g. `FromInt(int)`, `FromString(string)`, etc. As far as I know I can't create `MyEnum.FromInt()` (static) extension method. So what are the possible approaches for this?

Comment: You make the extension method on `int` and `string`, not the `enum`...

Comment: wouldn't that kind of pollute `int` and `string` since they are used a lot and mostly not related to my enum?

Comment: Such a method (like my ToEnum<> below) would be general purpose enough (almost like ToString(), almost).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would avoid polluting int or string with extension methods for enums, instead a good old fashioned static helper class might be in order.

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
   public static T FromInt<T>(int value)
   {
       return (T)value;
   }

  public static T FromString<T>(string value)
  {
     return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T),value);
  }
}
```

Comment: `FromInt` does not compile for me, _Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'_ ?

Comment: Is `T` an enum? Is it an int enum?

Comment: I'm not even calling it and compilation fails - I got this to work instead: `public static T ToEnum<T>(this int value)
        {
            return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString());
        }`

Comment: Big chances of getting exceptions, I would use a combination of this solutions with Reddeckwins's solution below (using IsDefined and TryParse) to avoid unnecessary problems, of course depending on the situation.

Answer (score 22):

Do you really need those extension methods?

```
MyEnum fromInt = (MyEnum)someIntValue;
MyEnum fromString = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), someStringValue, true);

int intFromEnum = (int)MyEnum.SomeValue;
string stringFromEnum = MyEnum.SomeValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 8):

The other way around would be possibly... the other way around ;) Extend int and string with **generic extension methods** which will take as type parameter the type of an enum:

```
public static TEnum ToEnum<TEnum>(this int val)
{
    return (TEnum) System.Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), val);
}
```

---

```
public static TEnum ToEnum<TEnum>(this string val)
{
    return (TEnum) System.Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), val);
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var redFromInt = 141.ToEnum<System.Drawing.KnownColor>();
var redFromString = "Red".ToEnum<System.Drawing.KnownColor>();
```

There is unfortunately no generic constraint for Enums, so we have to check TEnum type during runtime; to simplify we'll leave that verification to `Enum.ToObject` and `Enum.Parse` methods.

Comment: I like that this is one method with different overloads.

Answer (score 4):

why do you want FromInt an extenstion method versus just casting it?

```
MyEnum fromInt;
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), intvalue))
{
    fromInt = (MyEnum) intvalue;
}
else
{
    //not valid
}
```

alternatively, for strings, you can use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

```
MyEnum fromString;
if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(stringvalue, out fromString))
{
    //succeeded
}
else
{
    //not valid
}
```

Comment: What if stringvalue and intvalue is not the same as the underlying value?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying.  Are you asking what happens in the string or int do not represent any of the enum values?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (for the string part of your question):

```
/// <summary>
/// Static class for generic parsing of string to enum
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the enum to be parsed to</typeparam>
public static class Enum<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the specified value from string to the given Enum type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Parse(string value)
    {
        //Null check
        if(value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        //Empty string check
        value = value.Trim();
        if(value.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must specify valid information for parsing in the string", "value");
        //Not enum check
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if(!t.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Type provided must be an Enum", "T");

        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
    }
}
```

(Partially inspired by: http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2007/09/13/my-new-little-friend-enum-lt-t-gt.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static Enum FromInt32(this Enum obj, Int32 value)
    {
        return (Enum)((Object)(value));
    }

    public static Enum FromString(this Enum obj, String value)
    {
        return (Enum)Enum.Parse(obj.GetType(), value);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public static class Int32Extensions
{
    public static Enum ToEnum(this Int32 obj)
    {
        return (Enum)((Object)(obj));
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static Enum ToEnum(this Enum obj, String value)
    {
        return (Enum)Enum.Parse(obj.GetType(), value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make extension methods on int and string.

Or make static method on some other static class. Maybe something like EnumHelper.FromInt(int).

But I would pose one question : Why do you want to convert to string or int? Its not how you normaly work with enumerables, except maybe serialisation. But that should be handled by some kind of infrastructure, not your own code.

Comment: re your question: I am creating a wrapper around more than one library. They don't have the same convention regarding some string, so I try to create an enum so that they'll have the same convention.